# protoc-gen-java code use Inline object prompt syntax error

Tags: java, go, protocol-buffers, protoc

### describe

I want to use java to call golang grpc.I used the old golang's consumer_proto.proto to gen java code

### process

```
protoc  --java_out=/home/xxx/src/main/java custom_proto.proto  

protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=/home/xxx/protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.7.0-linux-x86_64.exe --grpc-java_out=/home/xxx/main/java custom_proto.proto
```

### result

I success gen my proto java file.but I find use Inline object prompt syntax error,the problem is from:

```
message RepGetClassBySchoolD {
     RequestRClassStruct     Class = 1;
}
```

the error is:

```
getClass() in xx classes in 'java.lang.Object';attempting to use incompatible return type
```

when I run the code,The error is:

```
Error:(92, 62) java: com.xxx.RepGetClassBySchoolD getClass() Unable to cover java.lang.Object's getClass()
```

The method to be overwritten is final

It happend at class RepGetClassBySchoolD:

```
public com.class100.service.usercenter.RequestRClassStruct getClass() {
return class_ == null ? com.class100.service.usercenter.RequestRClassStruct.getDefaultInstance() : class_;
```

}

Is there a way to make this work? Or any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Fix it by:

### reason:

```
message CascadeStuGRPC {
    RequestRStudentStruct requestRStudentStruct =1 ;
    RequestRTeachingAssistantStruct requestRTeachingAssistantStruct = 2;
    RequestRSchoolStruct    SchoolLogin = 3;
    RequestRClassStruct     Class = 4;
}

message RepGetClassBySchoolD {
    RequestRClassStruct    Class = 1;
}
```

It's just because what I define two message with common name "Class",I have been using this in golang for a long time, and it will not go wrong,but in proto-gen-jave it,It will produce this error.

### fix:

just fix it by another name like this:

```
message CascadeStuGRPC {
    RequestRStudentStruct requestRStudentStruct =1 ;
    RequestRTeachingAssistantStruct requestRTeachingAssistantStruct = 2;
    RequestRSchoolStruct    SchoolLogin = 3;
    RequestRClassStruct     ClassCa = 4;
}

message RepGetClassBySchoolD {
    RequestRClassStruct    ClassSch = 1;
}
```

it gen like this:

```
 public com.class100.service.usercenter.RequestRClassStruct getClassCa() {
return classCa_ == null ? com.class100.service.usercenter.RequestRClassStruct.getDefaultInstance() : classCa_;}
```

It gen getClassCa() not getClass(),This problem is solved.